# c++ Add or subtract values to the date

Tags: c++, date, time, addition

I couldn't figüre out how to add values to the date. Imagine, I have a date like 2012-5-15. After I parsed it, I obtained the year,month and day seperately and I tried to convert to my exact date to the days by using time_t and mktime. Do I have a chance to convert it back to the date from the days or seconds I found?  Here is part of my code trying to do this;

```
if(operation="+"){
    tm tm1=make_tm(year,mon,day);
    time_t time1=mktime(&tm1);
    int seconds_per_day=60*60*24;
    time_t second=time1/seconds_per_day;
    int sum=second //Trying to convert to the int from my time_t, don't know      
                   //if it is neccesary
    sum=sum+value //the value I want to add
```

So, basically if I give an input like 2012/5/15. It calculates how many days it passed by using the method but I just need to convert it to date and make it shown. Do you have any idea?

Comment: time_t is the number of seconds since the epoc (Jan 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC). See [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time)

Comment: sorry if this is irelevant, but if you used the `<chrono>` library, you you already have operator `+` defined for the classes.

Comment: Yes, I converted it to the days after that and stored it as a day. Then, I added my value to that day. I could see my date as number of days but I need to convert it to the date again(YYYY-M-D)

Comment: I did not use the chrono library. Actually, I tried but umm.... Is there any other way?

Comment: There always is, I just haven't figured it out yet! ;P

Comment: as i understood input will be a date like 2012-5-15(any date in this format), can you explain the output or the processing you want from this input?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for a way to add days to a particular date, here is a way to do it in similar terms to your attempt:

```
tm addDays(tm t1, int days)
{
    time_t epoch = mktime(&t1);
    epoch += (60*60*24 * days);
    return *localtime(&epoch);
}
```

Then use the returned `tm` structure and access the `tm_year`, `tm_mon` and `tm_mday` members to get the `yyyymmdd` required output. A very rough and ready example (no proper formatting):

```
tm t1;
std::fill((char*)&t1, (char*)&t1 + sizeof(t1), 0);
t1.tm_year = 2016;
t1.tm_mon = 8;
t1.tm_mday = 2;

auto result = addDays(t1, 30);

std::cout << result.tm_year << '/' << result.tm_mon << '/' << result.tm_mday << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [free, open-source C++11/14 library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) to do what you want with very nice syntax, and unparalleled performance.

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    year_month_day x = sys_days{2012_y/may/15} + days{55};
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
2012-07-09
```

If you would prefer to write this yourself, [here are the algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) used by this date library.  But the date library wraps everything up in a type-safe manner which catches many errors at compile time.

The date library is also nothing more than an extension of the `<chrono>` library, and so is very compatible with it:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    auto x = sys_days{2012_y/may/15} + days{55} + 7h + 30min;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}

2012-07-09 07:30
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everybody for your attention but I figured out the problem in another way. Here is my way;

```
tm tm1=make_tm(year,mon,day);//of course I had an make_tm as struct
time_t time1=mktime(&tm1);
time1=time1+value*86400-86400 //because it was a second, I needed to convert the day to second. Then, I don't know why but it showed extra one day. So, again I subtracted 86400 then the problem solved.
char *cb=ctime(&time1);
cout<<cb<<endl;
```